# How to find what datatype/ object/ collection 'var' stores in c#

Tags: c#, var

I'm new to coding and was given a task to validate a variable is a collection or not. So, how to find what datatype is stored in `var Banks =  ("ICICI", "KOTAK", "HDFC");`

Comment: I can tell you that: it's a `ValueTuple<string, string, string>`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to know how to find out what type var is storing and is there a method to find out

Comment: `Banks.GetType();` should give you all information about the type.

Comment: I just told you: they're all `string`, how could they not be?

Comment: If you're using VisualStudio, if you hover over `var` you can see the type. Also, with `Ctrl`+`.` you can tell VS to replace it by the explicit type.

Comment: Do you mean the type of the *variable* or the type of the *value inside the variable*? And do you want to know when you, a human, is looking at the code; or, do you want the program to figure it out while it's running?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the type of any object using the [Object.GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-5.0%5D) Method.

```
var Banks =  ("ICICI", "KOTAK", "HDFC");
Console.Write(Banks.GetType());
```

Will print out `System.ValueTuple'3[System.String,System.String,System.String]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0) consisting of three strings. The `ValueTuple` structure was introduced in C# 7.0.

You can access the members in your example with `Banks.Item1`, `Banks.Item2` and `Banks.Item3`.

If you are working with Visual Studio just hover over the `var` keyword. A tooltip will then show you its type.

Answer (score 0):

You can allways find out the type of a variable by using .GetType like:

```
Console.WriteLine(Banks.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s a ValueTuple<string, string, string>

I made this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4oZ3P

This is a collection:

```
var Banks = new [] { "ICICI", "KOTAK", "HDFC" };
```

The syntax is a bit diferent.